# Why does scraping a Persian website with a non-English URL generate errors?

Tags: python, url, scrapy

I am attempting to scrape a Persian website with the following code:

```
import urlparse, urllib
parts = urlparse.urlsplit(u'http://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/صفحهٔ_اصلی')
parts = parts._replace(path=urllib.quote(parts.path.encode('utf8')))
encoded_url = parts.geturl().encode('ascii')
'https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%87%D9%94_%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%DB%8C'
```

I get this error message in the prompt when I run my crawler:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named urlparse

And in VS Code there are three underlined words. When I click on them, the following error messages are displayed:

1. Unable to import 'scrapy'
2. Unable to import 'urlparse'
3. Module 'urllib' has no quote member

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Module not found is not a problem with code, it's a problem with your env. are you sure have those installed? I think urlparse is only available in python 2, are sure you are running this code with the right python version?

Comment: I tried to run your code with python 2 and it works perfectly, you need to check that you are using python 2 when running this piece of code. you check python version with ```python --version```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib.parse
parts = urllib.parse.urlsplit(u'http://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/صفحهٔ_اصلی')
parts = parts._replace(path=urllib.parse.quote(parts.path.encode('utf8')))
encoded_url = parts.geturl().encode('ascii')
'https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D9%87%D9%94_%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%DB%8C'

print(encoded_url)
```

This code runs in python 3.* environment as urlparse library was replaced by urllib.parse

Answer (score 0):

By the error messages you don't have them, go to their respective site and look on how to install.

1 [Note for urlparse change](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) it is now named urllib.parse not urlparse

2 [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Answer (score -1):

You should only use this:

**FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='UTF-8'**

in your settings.py file.